# How to measure size of facial features?

Tags: css, opencv, javacv, face-detection

**What I Have**

I have been coding using Opencv in Java and I have been successful in getting a face detected and cropped.

**My Problem Statement**

My next move was to calculate the size of the facial features like nose-width, distance between the corners of the eye but I cant seem to be able to do it with the haarcascades as the width metric on different images clicked with different angles seem to have varying values.

**The Solution that I want**

I wanted to know if anybody can help me in giving me a solution from which I can calculate the distance between the edges of the nose or the distance between the corners of the eye. I read about ASM but is that the best solution?

Any kind of enlightenment on this topic would be greatly helpful.

Comment: **I have been coding using Opencv in Java** and Where your codes?

Comment: @anonymousxxx I have the codes which can detect face and crop the Image the face image as I have clearly mentioned above. The codes can be found everywhere in the net. But my problem is  not what I have achieved, it is about the solution that I want. I would be grateful if you could suggest me a solution to the problem or just an advice to move forward on it. Thanks.

Comment: **The codes can be found everywhere in the net**, and my answer is solution for your problem can be found everywhere in the net.

Comment: @anonymousxxx If you need a solution for the face detect then here is the link http://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/samples/FaceRecognition.java?r=39d251265715f7204573d0b68868c7749fee84d6. Now that I have helped you finding the **everywhere** portion of the net, can you please give me a solution to my problem if you have one.

Comment: **You have been coding** but you give me code's other people? I don't have solution for you but just give some ref for you. Haarcascades not detection specific point of object (e.g corners). You have codes for detection eyes and nose. If you want detection distance of eye, you need specific for detection point of eye (corner). If you need calculation nose-width, should detection where is center of nose-height. ref : [Eye Cascade](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~shameem/haarcascade_eye.html)

Comment: @anonymousxxx I am sorry the code is used for something classified so I cannot show it. :) I got this reference so that at least I could give you some idea on what I am doing. Thank You very much for your advice. :)

Comment: Can I ask why you need the distance between the edges of the nose or the distance between the eyes?

I hope it's not for face recognition:)

Comment: @GilLevi you kinda guessed it right, but my intention is not completely face recognition. I wanna expand it for more uses later on. Hence, can you please provide me some walk through on my problem?

Comment: Using distance between facial features is really not a good approach for face recognition. Try LBP features + SVM for example or just google for recent approaches. You can also use the site face-rec.org to learn about the subject.

Comment: @GilLevi thank you so much for the advice. I will try and get this implemented. If I run into any future problems while accomplishing this can I drop you a mail?

Comment: I don't have much experience with OpenCV, so I'm not sure I could help, but not problem.

Also, OpenCV has a module for face recognition, you should check it out.